# distributing $7$ distinct biscuits to $4$ children with following conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $7$ distinct biscuits be distributed among $4$ (distinguishable) children such that one child receives $1$ biscuit and the other children receive precisely $2$ biscuits each.

My approach is:

For the child that has $1$ biscuit, there are $4$ choices of choosing the child and $7$ choices of choosing the biscuit.

For the second child that has $2$ biscuits, there are $3$ choices of choosing the child and $C(6,2)$ choices for biscuits.

For the third child that has $2$ biscuits, there are $2$ choices of choosing the child and $C(4,2)$ choices for biscuits.

For the final child that has $2$ biscuits, there are $1$ choices of choosing the child and $C(2,2)$ choices for biscuits.

So, my answer is $4 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 \cdot C(6,2) \cdot 2 \cdot C(4,2) \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 15120$.

However, the answer is $2520$.  Have no idea how to get the correct answer.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have over counted.  Once the child who receives only one biscuit has been selected there is otherwise no way of distinguishing the children based on the number of biscuits they receive.  Instead, for the second, third, and fourth children, rather than randomly picking which is which... let us pick them according to a predetermined rule such as age or name.

Comment: This would give an answer of $4\cdot 7\cdot \binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}=2520$, precisely $\frac{1}{6}$ of your initial attempt.  Note:  letting color represent the person and number represent the flavor of biscuit, the outcomes $(1),\color{red}{(2,3)},\color{blue}{(4,5)},\color{green}{(6,7)}$ is considered the same as $(1),\color{blue}{(4,5)},\color{green}{(6,7)},\color{red}{(2,3)}$ though you had considered them as different despite the same children receiving the same distribution of biscuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the children be $A, B, C, D$. There are four cases. Either $A$ is the child who receives one biscuit, $B$ is said child and so on. In each case the child who receives one biscuit has $7$ choices and then we distribute the remaining $6$ biscuits among the remaining $3$ children with each receiving $2$ biscuits, which can be done in $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ ways. Putting the pieces altogether, there are
$$
4\times 7\times\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}=2520
$$
ways.

Answer (score 0):

First off, select the child that gets one biscuit. As you said, there are $4$ possible choices for the child and $7$ for the biscuit, giving $4 \times 7$ possibilities.

To count the ways to distribute the remaining biscuits to the other children, imagine to clone each child. So, if you name the children $A$, $B$ and $C$, you now have:
$$A, A', B, B', C, C'$$

Now, you have to distribute exactly one biscuit to each. This is a permutation of $6$ elements, so the total number is $6!$. But wait: a child and its clone are the same person, so we don't have to distinguish between them. Thus you have to divide this number by $2!$ (for each child), thereby getting
$$4 \times 7 \times \frac{6!}{2!2!2!} = 2520$$